# Unable to edit Android Studio build files

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, build, build.gradle

I am currently trying to run a music player app, which is made using ***Kotlin*** on ***Android Studio***. Unfortunately when I click the "run" button it says "Build failed" and the following error appears:

**"app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\crrl\beatplayer\repository\PlaylistRepository.java:6: error: class PlayListRepository is public, should be declared in a file named PlayListRepository.java
public abstract interface PlayListRepository"**

I think I know why it is showing this error; because the name of the interface is different from the filename(**PlaylistRepository.java**), currently this file resides in my build folder in "app" as you can see from the path.

I have tried to search how to change the the contents of the file and rename it, but whenever I click "run" after implementing the changes, it reverts back to the old filename and content as if I didn't change anything and shows the same error.

```
import java.lang.System;

@kotlin.Metadata(mv = {1, 1, 15}, bv = {1, 0, 3}, k = 1, d1 = {"\u00006\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u0000\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0010\t\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0010\u000e\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0010\b\n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0010 \n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0010\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0002\bf\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001J\u0012\u0010\u0002\u001a\u00020\u00032\b\u0010\u0004\u001a\u0004\u0018\u00010\u0005H&J\u0010\u0010\u0006\u001a\u00020\u00072\u0006\u0010\b\u001a\u00020\u0003H&J\u000e\u0010\t\u001a\b\u0012\u0004\u0012\u00020\u000b0\nH&J\u0016\u0010\f\u001a\b\u0012\u0004\u0012\u00020\r0\n2\u0006\u0010\b\u001a\u00020\u0003H&J\u0018\u0010\u000e\u001a\u00020\u000f2\u0006\u0010\b\u001a\u00020\u00032\u0006\u0010\u0010\u001a\u00020\u0003H&\u00a8\u0006\u0011"}, d2 = {"Lcom/crrl/beatplayer/repository/PlayListRepository;", "", "createPlaylist", "", "name", "", "deletePlaylist", "", "playlistId", "getPlaylists", "", "Lcom/crrl/beatplayer/models/Playlist;", "getSongsInPlaylist", "Lcom/crrl/beatplayer/models/Song;", "removeFromPlaylist", "", "id", "app_debug"})
public interface PlayListRepository {

    public abstract long createPlaylist(@org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable()
    java.lang.String name) throws java.lang.IllegalStateException;

    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    public abstract java.util.List<com.crrl.beatplayer.models.Playlist> getPlaylists();

    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    public abstract java.util.List<com.crrl.beatplayer.models.Song> getSongsInPlaylist(long playlistId);

    public abstract void removeFromPlaylist(long playlistId, long id);

    public abstract int deletePlaylist(long playlistId);
}
```

Is there a fix to this? I have tried everything, nothing seems to work!

Comment: the resources under build folder is meant to be changed after every build. you have the change the library/module you are using before build

Comment: you should not try to change anything in build folder, as everything there is generated during build process, and the changes will vanish right when you press Build. Instead find corresponding file in your sources

Comment: @Vladyslav Matviienko So you are suggesting that I find the corresponding file in my src folder and make my changes there? If so, then I don't see any problem in that file.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I got it to run!!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to just change the filename which is located in the source folder to what Android Studio was suggesting.